# Simple console menu backend with calculator implementation in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, classes

I've written a simple calculator in Python. I want to show not much effect of the action but the logic behind it, by that I mean console menu implementation in the `Menu` class. I'm curious about what I can improve in the `Menu` class, what do you think about it and other helper functions? I'd like to hear also what useful functionality can I add to the `Menu` library.

Here's code with an example menu implementation in the calculator:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import enum
from collections import OrderedDict     # I used OrderedDict due to the move_to_end function
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any


@enum.unique
class BannerStyle(enum.IntEnum):
    FRAME_BOX = enum.auto()
    HASH = enum.auto()


def print_banner(title, style=BannerStyle.FRAME_BOX):
    match style:
        case BannerStyle.FRAME_BOX:
            print('-' * (len(title) + 4))
            print(f'| {title:^} |')
            print('-' * (len(title) + 4))
        case BannerStyle.HASH:
            print('#' * (len(title) + 4))
            print(f'# {title:^} #')
            print('#' * (len(title) + 4))


def read_int(prompt='Enter an integer: ', errmsg='Not an integer.', default=None):
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = input(prompt)
            if default and not user_input:
                user_input = default
            return int(user_input)
        except ValueError:
            print(errmsg)


def read_float(prompt='Enter an floating point number: ', errmsg='Not an floating point number.', default=None):
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = input(prompt)
            if default and not user_input:
                user_input = default
            return float(user_input)
        except ValueError:
            print(errmsg)


def print_list(lst):
    for idx, item in enumerate(lst):
        print(f'{idx}) {item}')


@dataclass
class UserChoice:
    idx: int
    choice: Any


def read_choice(choices, prompt='Your choice (enter an integer): ', errmsg='Invalid choice.', default=None):
    if default and default not in choices:
        raise ValueError(f'default value {default} is not present in choices argument')
    while True:
        try:
            print('Available choices:')
            print_list(choices)
            user_input = input(prompt)
            if default and not user_input:
                user_input = default
            user_input = int(user_input)
            if not 0 <= user_input < len(choices):
                raise ValueError
            return UserChoice(idx=user_input, choice=choices[user_input])
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            print(errmsg)


class Menu:
    def __init__(self, title, banner_style=BannerStyle.FRAME_BOX):
        self.title = title
        self.active = True
        self.items = OrderedDict({'Quit': self.quit})
        self.banner_style = banner_style

    def add_item(self, title, func):
        self.items[title] = func
        self.items.move_to_end('Quit')

    def remove_item(self, title):
        del self.items[title]

    def add_submenu(self, title, submenu):
        self.items[title] = submenu.quit

    @property
    def _items_titles(self):
        return list(self.items.keys())

    def invoke(self, title):
        return self.items[title]()

    def quit(self):
        self.active = False

    def loop(self):
        while self.active:
            print_banner(self.title)
            user_input = read_choice(self._items_titles).idx
            self.invoke(self._items_titles[user_input])

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MenuItem(title='{self.title}', active={self.active})"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class CalculatorUI:
    def add(self):
        self._read_numbers()
        print(f'The result is {self.a + self.b}')

    def subtract(self):
        self._read_numbers()
        print(f'The result is {self.a - self.b}')

    def multiply(self):
        self._read_numbers()
        print(f'The result is {self.a * self.b}')

    def divide(self):
        self._read_numbers_div()
        print(f'The result is {self.a / self.b}')

    def modulo(self):
        self._read_numbers_div()
        print(f'The result is {self.a % self.b}')

    def _read_numbers(self):
        self.a = read_float('Enter first number: ')
        self.b = read_float('Enter second number: ')

    def _read_numbers_div(self):
        self.a = read_float('Enter first number: ')
        self.b = read_float('Enter second number: ')
        while self.b == 0:
            print('Number cannot be zero.')
            self.b = read_float('Enter second number: ')


calc = CalculatorUI()


def test_menu():
    menu = Menu(title='Welcome to calculator')
    menu.add_item('Add', calc.add)
    menu.add_item('Subtract', calc.subtract)
    menu.add_item('Multiply', calc.multiply)
    menu.add_item('Divide', calc.divide)
    menu.add_item('Modulo', calc.modulo)
    menu.loop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_menu()
```

Answer (score 4):

In `f'| {title:^} |'`, there's no padding, so does the centre-specifier have any effect? I don't think it does.

`read_int` and `read_float` should be collapsed to one function that accepts a type and a name. Also, the default should not be a string; it should be of the numeral type.

Your functions are missing PEP484 type hints. It's not enough to hint your class members.

`CalculatorUI` is not a well-modelled class. `a` and `b` should not be properties, and in fact there's no reason for this to be a class.

Why does `Menu` have a `remove_item`? It's never called, and it probably never *should* be called. The menu should be an immutable sequence of items. So `Menu` is also not a well-modelled class either. `active` should not be a property, and not even a variable of any kind: you should just be able to `break` out of the loop once it's appropriate.

It's not a good idea for a choice-from-sequence to return a title string. The choice should instead return a callable or object that can be used directly, without something like `invoke` needing to exist.

Make a temporary variable to store your banner character.

`if default and not user_input:` is dangerous. What happens on `0`? `0` is falsey.

`idx` in `UserChoice` is redundant. One hint as to why this is: you don't use it in `print_items`.

Don't overwrite a variable of one type with a value of a second type as you do in `user_input = int(user_input)`.

For immutable data, `NamedTuple` is a better choice than `@dataclass`.

You capture a "banner style" in your menu constructor but then fail to pass it to the banner rendering method.

Default-supporting methods could look like

```
def read_number(name: str, type_: Type[EntryNumber], default: Optional[EntryNumber] = None) -> EntryNumber:
    if default is None:
        prompt = f'Enter {name}: '
    else:
        prompt = f'Enter {name} [{default}]: '

    while True:
        try:
            user_input = input(prompt)
            if user_input == '':
                if default is not None:
                    return default
                continue
            return type_(user_input)
        except ValueError:
            print(f'Invalid {name}.')

def read_choice(
    choices: Sequence[UserChoice],
    default: Optional[UserChoice] = None,
) -> UserChoice:
    if default is not None and default not in choices:
        raise ValueError(f'default value {default} is not present in choices argument')

    prompt = '\n'.join(format_items(choices))

    while True:
        try:
            print(prompt)
            print('Your choice (enter an integer): ')
            user_input = input(prompt)
            if user_input == '':
                if default is not None:
                    return default
                continue

            index = int(user_input)
            if 0 <= index < len(choices):
                return choices[index]
            print('Choice out of range.')
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid integer.')
```

but you never use the default functionality, so delete it.

It is unusual to have a 0-based user-facing menu selection. Strongly consider using 1-based instead.

### Suggested

```
import enum
from numbers import Number
from typing import Callable, Iterable, NamedTuple, Optional, Sequence, Type, TypeVar


@enum.unique
class BannerStyle(enum.IntEnum):
    FRAME_BOX = enum.auto()
    HASH = enum.auto()


EntryNumber = TypeVar('EntryNumber', bound=Number)


def read_number(prompt: str, type_: Type[EntryNumber]) -> EntryNumber:
    while True:
        try:
            return type_(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print(f'Invalid number.')


class UserChoice(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    invoke: Callable[[], Optional[bool]]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


def format_items(choices: Iterable[UserChoice]) -> Iterable[str]:
    for idx, item in enumerate(choices, 1):
        yield f'{idx}) {item}'


def read_choice(choices: Sequence[UserChoice]) -> UserChoice:
    prompt = '\n'.join((
        *format_items(choices),
        'Your choice (enter an integer): '
    ))

    while True:
        index = read_number(prompt, int) - 1
        if 0 <= index < len(choices):
            return choices[index]
        print('Choice out of range.')


class Menu(NamedTuple):
    title: str
    items: Sequence[UserChoice]
    banner_style: BannerStyle = BannerStyle.FRAME_BOX

    def print_banner(self) -> None:
        match self.banner_style:
            case BannerStyle.FRAME_BOX:
                top_char = '-'
                edge_char = '|'
            case BannerStyle.HASH:
                top_char = '#'
                edge_char = '#'
            case _:
                raise ValueError(f'Invalid style {self.banner_style}')

        top = top_char * (len(self.title) + 4)
        print(top)
        print(f'{edge_char} {self.title} {edge_char}')
        print(top)

    def loop(self) -> None:
        while True:
            self.print_banner()
            choice = read_choice(self.items)
            if choice.invoke():
                break
            print()


def read_numbers() -> tuple[float, float]:
    return (
        read_number('Enter first number: ', float),
        read_number('Enter second number: ', float),
    )


def read_numbers_div() -> tuple[float, float]:
    a = read_number('Enter first number: ', float)
    while True:
        b = read_number('Enter second number (cannot be 0): ', float)
        if b != 0:
            return a, b


def add() -> None:
    a, b = read_numbers()
    print(f'The result is {a + b}')


def subtract() -> None:
    a, b = read_numbers()
    print(f'The result is {a - b}')


def multiply() -> None:
    a, b = read_numbers()
    print(f'The result is {a * b}')


def divide() -> None:
    a, b = read_numbers_div()
    print(f'The result is {a / b}')


def modulo() -> None:
    a, b = read_numbers_div()
    print(f'The result is {a % b}')


def quit_menu() -> bool:
    return True


def test_menu() -> None:
    menu = Menu(
        title='Welcome to calculator',
        items=(
            UserChoice('Add', add),
            UserChoice('Subtract', subtract),
            UserChoice('Multiply', multiply),
            UserChoice('Divide', divide),
            UserChoice('Modulo', modulo),
            UserChoice('Quit', quit_menu),
        ),
    )
    menu.loop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_menu()
```

Comment: Is `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` necessary in the new Python programs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14083111/313768

Comment: Should I use type hints in Django too?

Comment: yes, definitely. Django is just Python.